# How to use async with lambdas which does not return anything?

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I have a simple lambda called inside async. But it gives a system_error.

```
#include<future>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::async([]()
    {
        std::cout << 42 << std::endl;
    });
    a.get();
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/GIyGI

Compiler: C++0x (gcc-4.5.1)

Any ideas?

Comment: This just seems like a bug in GCC 4.5. Your code is valid AFAICT and works with clang (trunk).

Comment: I tried with GCC 4.6.1 as well. same error. When I compiled with -pthread it works fine.

Comment: @bames53 clang trunk can codegen lambdas?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It did for that one. I'm not certain how complete support is yet and I haven't tried anything complex. There's probably a reason they haven't updated their C++ support page to indicate lambda's are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you need to compile with the `-pthread` option.

Comment: Yes. it runs fine with -pthread option but why is it like this? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It's "sort of" documented. For example, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_concurrency.html where it amusely (because this is the documentation) talks about how it's very platform-dependent and not very well documented.